# Как и где хранить внутрисистемные пароли?

Tags: java

Есть API на Java. Он работает с БД + еще одним сервисом по HTTP. Нужно безопасно сохранить пароль от БД и еще кой чего статическое.

Есть мысль хранить зашифрованный пароль где-нибудь и потом его расшифровывать для соединения с БД. Хочу посоветоваться с людьми, которые уже решали похожие задачи. В общем подскажите плз.

Веб приложение, фреймворки не использовал.

Comment: какого рода приложение? веб? настольное? использован ли какой-то фреймворк?

Comment: БД какая? Они нынче почти все умеют по ssl по сертификату авторизовывать. Ну и опять же, что мешает хранить в `properties` с грамотно выставленными правами?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов решения:

1. Сервер конфигураций/хранилище секретов - [Consul](https://www.consul.io/), [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/), [Torus](https://www.torus.sh/), etc. Приложение в момент старта обращается к ним и получает все необходимые секреты.
2. Приложение получает секреты через переменные окружения - [The twelve-factor app](https://12factor.net/).
3. Приложение читает секреты из файла, который создается системой управление инфраструктурой при разворачивании приложения - [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/), [Puppet](https://puppet.com/), [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), etc.